# regexp_replace function in hive to format SSN

Tags: sql, regex, hive, regexp-replace

Can anyone please help? I want to replace SSN with dash for the given string using regexp_replace in Hive SQL

I am trying with below query but get the result as `1-2-3`

```
select regexp_replace("123790634", '([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})', '\\1-\\2-\\3');
```

My output should look like 123-79-0634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefer using the dollar prefixed format instead

`select regexp_replace('123790634', '(.{3})(.{2})(.{4})','$1-$2-$3')`

Comment: Thank you very much. Dollar prefixed format worked.

Comment: @LHS you're welcome. Indeed, Oracle also has regexp_replace function and if `'\1-\2-\3'` is used as the format, it works as expected for Oracle. Can you try with `\1-\2-\3` ( *wrapped with double or single quotes* ) for the first query?

Comment: First query did not work in hive out put : select regexp_replace('123790634', '([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})', "\\1-\\2-\\3");
OK
1-2-3

Comment: @LHS I meant whether you tried with `\1-\2-\3`, but not `\\1-\\2-\\3` ...

Comment: yes, tried with single backslash and it is the same result i.e 1-2-3